# How to fill a matrix by proportion?

Tags: r, for-loop, matrix, lapply, adjacency-matrix

I'm trying to create aa 20x20 matrix filled with numbers from -1:2. However, I don't want it to be random but by proportion that I decide.

For example, I would want 0.10 of the cells to be -1, 0.60 to be 0, 0.20 to be 1, 0.10 to be 2.

This code was able to get me a matrix with all of the values I want, but I don't know how to edit it to specify the proportion of each value I want.

```
r <- 20
c <- 20
mat <- matrix(sample(-1:2,r*c, replace=TRUE),r,c)
```

Comment: IN `sample`, there is `prob`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use the `prob` argument from `sample`

```
matrix(sample(-1:2,r*c, replace=TRUE, prob = c(0.1, 0.6, 0.2, 0.2)), r, c)
```

Answer (score 1):

```r
r <- 20
c <- 20

ncell = r * c
val = c(-1, 0.2,  1, 2)
p = c(0.1, 0.6, 0.2, 0.1)
fill = rep(val, ceiling(p * ncell))[1:ncell]

mat <- matrix(data = sample(fill), nrow = r, ncol = c)
prop.table(table(mat))
#> mat
#>  -1 0.2   1   2 
#> 0.1 0.6 0.2 0.1
```

<sup>Created on 2019-09-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>